# Google Place Autocomplete Address Form. How to Get each component of the address from the place details?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

The following page takes you to the Google Maps API - Place Autocomplete Address Form which is a working example of what you could potentially do with it.

[Place Autocomplete Address Form](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

In his page you see the code sample and in it, the following subroutine:

```
// Get each component of the address from the place details
// and fill the corresponding field on the form.

  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {

    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];

    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
    var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
    document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }

  }
```

As you can see, this For Loop code is very dynamic..

Can anyone show me how to return each Address Field separately into their own variables OR into an array so that I can rebuild it back into a string in any given order I choose?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object js

```
  var your_obj = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {

    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];

    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;

      your_obj[addresType] = val;

    }

  }

//and after that you can use it where you uant like:
var postal_code = your_obj['postal_code'];

//check first console.log() to know all items in your_obj
console.log(your_obj);
```